# Notification being cancelled by another one in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, notifications, sms, android-5.0-lollipop, persistent

I create a notification in Service (launched from the BroadcastReceiver) this way:

```
this.notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentTitle("Foo")
    .setContentText("Bar")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .build();
this.initializeNotificationSound(volumne, Uri.parse(melody));
this.initializeNotificationVibration();

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
this.notificationManager.cancelAll();
this.notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

This notification is set when a particular SMS is received. I want to create a notification which will play a defined melody and will not be interrupted by the standard SMS notification.

This functionality works pretty good, however in lollipop, following scenario happens:

1. SMS is received
2. My notification is launched
3. After some time, notification sound is stopped and default SMS ringtone is played

This happens only when ringtone mode is silent. Otherwise, it works as expected, because of the cancelAll() method, which interrupts the SMS notification.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change that. If you notice, when more than one notifications are created at the same time, even from a sole application(e.g. Facebook), the sound they make is played simultaneously. This has to do with the notification management of android system itself. Maybe the problem you are facing happens due to some code changes made to the specific Android system version (API level), maybe to the `cancelAll()` method. One solution would be to find the appropriate line of code for checking current system version. For example:

```
if(System_version <= lollipop) {
//code works fine. Keep as it is
}
else{
//find the appropriate method and call it here.
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate one of following: 1: run another notification from the "stack" only after I cancel mine. 2. Start my notification again, after the other one (which interrupted mine) is finished.

Comment: 1: Try searching [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), and find the appropriate flag for you to use.
2: Try 1 and let me know if it works